# Abrir enlace en nueva pestaña y cerrarla

Tags: html

Es posible **`abrir un enlace en una nueva pestaña y luego cerrarla`** automáticamente para permanecer en la misma página donde me encontraba?

**Ej:**

```
<a href="pagina.html" target="_blank">Enlace</a>
```

Con esto se que abre en una nueva pestaña.  Es posible hacer que una vez abierta `página.html` se cierre sola y vuelva a la página anterior ?

Comment: Da un viztazo a "window.close()" dentro de las instrucciones de javascript.

Comment: Hola, gracias por reponder, eso es una función JS, no? Lo que necesito es que se cierre la pestaña, pero no puedo modificar el código de pagina.html, existe otra manera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí es posible , haciendo uso de de los métodos [open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) y [close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) del objeto [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) , creas un enlace como lo presentaste.

```
<a id="link">Enlace</a>
```

Luego desde `Javascript` agregas el evento `click` a dicho `link` y realizamos el `open` de la url y luego de un cierto tiempo la cerramos `close` , haciendo uso de `setTimeout`

```
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", function(){
    const ventana = window.open("https://google.com.pe","_blank");
    setTimeout(function(){
        ventana.close();
    }, 5000); /* 5 Segundos*/
});
```

Comment: Excelente!!! Muchas gracias!!!